# "up" in "had been dammed up"

Tags: phrase-usage

Can you explain to me why it isn't enough to say "had been dammed", but there is also "up" in the phrase. The text is:

> Dr. Howlett turned, straining against his seat belt to talk with Chad and Kate. He had to shout over the engine noise: "Our first stop is right in the middle of a 1976 earthquake area," he said. "I remeber flying over it a few years after the earthquake, and seeing where the vegetation had been stripped from the sides of the mountains, and rivers **had been dammed up**. To look at it today, you'd never know there had been one of the biggest earthquakes ever in this region."

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*dam*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dam#h2):

> 1 : to provide or restrain with a barrier that prevents the flow of water : to provide or restrain with a dam …
>       // *dam* a river
>   2 : to stop up : BLOCK
>       // *damming* up their emotions

Although *up* doesn't need to follow *dam*, it often does, and *dam up* has become a common phrase.

---

According to [Google NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20been%20dammed%2C%20had%20been%20dammed%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20been%20dammed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20been%20dammed%20up%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chad%20been%20dammed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20been%20dammed%20up%3B%2Cc0), *dam* on its own is twice as common as *dam up* in print, but *dam up* is still used:

[image: had been dammed versus had been dammed up]

---

Verbs are often followed by prepositions even when they don't have to be, because they add to (or emphasize) the mental picture of what's going on.

In this particular case, *stop up* (which *dam* is synonymous to) actually requires *up* to be meaningful in this sense. You would not normally say that *the drain is stopped* but that *the drain is stopped* ***up***. If we are used to using *stopped up*, it's not that strange to also use with *dammed up*.

---

Additionally, I suspect that the use of the preposition here helps distinguish between *it had been* ***dammed*** and *it had been* ***damned***. (Note the spelling.)

The verbs *dam* and *damn* are very similar, and are pronounced identically. (Although the past tense versions do have a subtle difference in pronunciation if you're listening for it.) But it would be quite unusual to say *it had been damned* ***up***. So, if we see the preposition, it's an indicator that it's talking about a blockage rather than a curse. While context is likely to indicate the difference anyway, such an additional cue can't hurt.

Comment: To add to this excellent answer, the [definition of up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) includes this: "ENTIRELY, COMPLETELY [...] used as an intensifier." The difference between "the drain is clogged" and "the drain is clogged **up**" is that the second one emphasizes that the drain is *entirely* clogged and no water at all can get through.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Interesting. I've never heard (or personally assumed) that particular distinction before—in this context anyway. If I heard *the drain is clogged* I would assume it to mean something identical to *the drain is clogged **up**.* To me, *up* doesn't add anything aside from the mental image or emphasis I suggested. If I meant to express something less than complete, only then would I add ***partially*** *clogged*. Otherwise, I'd assume the clog already was total.